# How to put an installer in my web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, installation

My MVC web site is almost finished and I need to put an installer on a web page for members only.

I have created a setup file from Smart Install Maker that will install different files to the member's computer.

I don't know how to put this setup file in my web page so that customers can install these files.

Could someone guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="/path/to/installer.zip">Download Software</a>
```